# Android fragment not appearing when list item is clicked

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm experimenting with Fragments in Android at the moment and this one is driving me nuts. I have a ListView in one Fragment containing a list of items (books). When I click on an item in the list, the Fragment *should* get swapped out for another Fragment containing the details for that item. But the Fragment isn't appearing, despite the setOnItemClickListener() method definitely working (I've got logcat messages confirming that the item in the ListView has been clicked. I also put another logcat message into the second Fragment's onCreateView() method so the Fragment appears to be created but isn't being inflated...

Here's FFBooksFragment, the Fragment which contains the ListView of items:

```
package com.example.android.gamebookcollector;

public class FFBooksFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "FFBooksFragment";

    private Button ffButton;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    private ListView booksList;

    private static final int STANDARD_APPBAR = 0;
    private static final int SEARCH_APPBAR = 1;

    private int mAppbarState;

    private AppBarLayout viewBooksToolbar, searchBar;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ffbooks, container, false);


        viewBooksToolbar = (AppBarLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.viewBooksToolbar);
        searchBar = (AppBarLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.searchBooksToolbar);

        booksList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.booksList);

        setUpGamebooksList();

        ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivSearchIcon);
        searchIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Clicked search icon in standard bar");
                toggleToolbarState();
            }
        });

        ImageView ivBackArrow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivBackArrow);
        ivBackArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Clicked back arrow in search bar");
                toggleToolbarState();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void toggleToolbarState() {

        if (mAppbarState==STANDARD_APPBAR) {
            setAppbarState(SEARCH_APPBAR);
        }else {
            setAppbarState(STANDARD_APPBAR);
        }
    }

    private void setAppbarState(int state) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Changing app bar state to " + state);

        mAppbarState = state;

        if(mAppbarState==STANDARD_APPBAR){
            searchBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewBooksToolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            View view = getView();
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

            try{
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }catch(NullPointerException e){
                Log.d(TAG, "setAppbar state: Null pointer exception. " + e.getMessage());

            }
        }

        else if (mAppbarState==SEARCH_APPBAR){
            viewBooksToolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            searchBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);

        }
    }

    private void setUpGamebooksList(){
        final ArrayList<Gamebook> gameBooks = new ArrayList<>();

        gameBooks.add(new Gamebook("1. Book title", "Book authors", "Publisher", "Year", R.drawable.image1));
        gameBooks.add(new Gamebook("2. Book title", "Book authors", "Publisher", "Year", R.drawable.image2));
        gameBooks.add(new Gamebook("3. Book title", "Book authors", "Publisher", "Year", R.drawable.image3));
        gameBooks.add(new Gamebook("4. Book title", "Book authors", "Publisher", "Year", R.drawable.image4));




        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_book_list_item, gameBooks, "drawable://");

        /*  Now we call the setAdapter() method on our booksList list and pass it our adapter. */
        booksList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Set up an onItemClickListener for checking to see if any book in the list is clicked on.
        // If so, go to the book fragment (which is blank for now).
        booksList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Navigating to book fragment...");
                BookFragment bookFragment = new BookFragment();

                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, bookFragment);

                // adding a string identifier string to the fragment, not really necessary right now but might as well do it
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(getString(R.string.book_fragment));
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setAppbarState(STANDARD_APPBAR);
    }
}
```

And here's BooksFragment, which should appear when an item in the above Fragment's ListView is clicked on:

```
package com.example.android.gamebookcollector;

public class BookFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "BookFragment";


    private android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_book, container, false);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.booksToolbar);

        Log.d(TAG, "Book fragment started...");

        // Set up the toolbar
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        ImageView ivBackArrow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivBackArrow);
        ivBackArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Back arrow clicked");
                // pop the previous fragment off the back stack (i.e. navigate back)
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        });

        /*  If the edit button is clicked, go to the edit book fragment */
        ImageView ivEdit = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_edit);
        ivEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Clicked the edit button...");

                EditBookFragment editBookFragment = new EditBookFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, editBookFragment);

                // adding a string identifier string to the fragment, not really necessary right now but might as well do it.
                // We can retrieve fragments by using their string identifer.
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(getString(R.string.edit_book_fragment));
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.book_menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.menuitem_delete:
                Log.d(TAG, "Delete book...");
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try to manage this process from the parent activity where both fragments will be placed.

Comment: Do you think this might be where the problem lies?

Comment: I think so. I don't now if the fragment could add the other fragment because the context is in the activity. It won't be the same if the second fragment was inside the first.

Comment: The posted code uses `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`, which means that the fragment is being managed by the activity's fragmentmanager. So I doubt going through the activity will solve things.

Comment: That being said, in general it is better practice to have the fragment speak only to its activity and never to another fragment, and one fragment creating another is pretty close to crossing that line.

Comment: Is your `FFBooksFragment` contained inside a view with id `fragmentContainer`? I see that you're calling `replace()` with that id; maybe your FFBooksFragment is simply overlaying that view? Or maybe that view is zero-size?

Comment: Ben P. Thanks dude, I think you're right. I'm replacing the wrong id. I'm not sure which one is the right one yet as I've been very sloppy naming stuff, so I have a bit of digging to do. But it looks like this is definitely what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem is you are doing the FindViewById Before the Fragment Return the View**

**Do This:**

Bind All the view in OnActivityCreated

And Kindly Check the Fragment Import Statement

//Please Import this

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

```html
public class FFBooksFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "FFBooksFragment";

    private Button ffButton;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    private ListView booksList;

    private static final int STANDARD_APPBAR = 0;
    private static final int SEARCH_APPBAR = 1;

    private int mAppbarState;

    private AppBarLayout viewBooksToolbar, searchBar;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ffbooks, container, false);
        return view;
    }
     @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        
        viewBooksToolbar = (AppBarLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewBooksToolbar);
    searchBar = (AppBarLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.searchBooksToolbar);

    booksList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.booksList);

    setUpGamebooksList();

    ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ivSearchIcon);
        searchIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Clicked search icon in standard bar");
            toggleToolbarState();
        }
    });

    ImageView ivBackArrow = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ivBackArrow);
        ivBackArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Clicked back arrow in search bar");
            toggleToolbarState();
        }
    });
    }

    private void toggleToolbarState() {

        if (mAppbarState==STANDARD_APPBAR) {
            setAppbarState(SEARCH_APPBAR);
        }else {
            setAppbarState(STANDARD_APPBAR);
        }
    }

    private void setAppbarState(int state) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Changing app bar state to " + state);

        mAppbarState = state;

        if(mAppbarState==STANDARD_APPBAR){
            searchBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewBooksToolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            View view = getView();
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

            try{
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }catch(NullPointerException e){
                Log.d(TAG, "setAppbar state: Null pointer exception. " + e.getMessage());

            }
        }

        else if (mAppbarState==SEARCH_APPBAR){
            viewBooksToolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            searchBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);

        }
    }

    private void setUpGamebooksList(){
        final ArrayList<Gamebook> gameBooks = new ArrayList<>();

        gameBooks.add(new Gamebook("1. Book title", "Book authors", "Publisher", "Year", R.drawable.image1));
        gameBooks.add(new Gamebook("2. Book title", "Book authors", "Publisher", "Year", R.drawable.image2));
        gameBooks.add(new Gamebook("3. Book title", "Book authors", "Publisher", "Year", R.drawable.image3));
        gameBooks.add(new Gamebook("4. Book title", "Book authors", "Publisher", "Year", R.drawable.image4));




        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_book_list_item, gameBooks, "drawable://");

        /*  Now we call the setAdapter() method on our booksList list and pass it our adapter. */
        booksList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Set up an onItemClickListener for checking to see if any book in the list is clicked on.
        // If so, go to the book fragment (which is blank for now).
        booksList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Navigating to book fragment...");
                BookFragment bookFragment = new BookFragment();

                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, bookFragment);

                // adding a string identifier string to the fragment, not really necessary right now but might as well do it
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(getString(R.string.book_fragment));
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setAppbarState(STANDARD_APPBAR);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Faiz Mir, but no luck with that solution.